# Отправка сообщений через Mail.ru SMTP python

Tags: python, smtp, smtplib

Мне нужно отправлять сообщения по почте `gmail` не работает в России, а с `yandex` свои приколы, остается только `mail`

мой код

```
import os
import smtplib
from email.header import Header
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

from .email_templates import EmailTemplates


class EmailSender:
    def __init__(self):
        self.sender = os.getenv('SMTP_EMAIL_FROM')
        self.username= os.getenv('SMTP_EMAIL_USERNAME')
        self.password = os.getenv('SMTP_EMAIL_FROM_PASSWORD')

        self.server = smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.mail.ru', 465)
        self.server.login(self.sender, self.password)
        self.server.auth_plain()

    def send_email(self, to_addr: str, theme: str, order_number: str):
        msg = MIMEMultipart()

        msg['From'] = self.sender
        msg['To'] = to_addr

        if theme == 'printed':
            msg['Subject'] = Header(EmailTemplates.printed.get('subject'), 'utf-8')
            msg.attach(
                MIMEText(f'{EmailTemplates.printed.get("message").format(order_number=order_number)}', 'plain', 'utf-8')
            )
        elif theme == 'canceled':
            msg['Subject'] = EmailTemplates.canceled.get('subject')
            msg.attach(
                MIMEText(f'{EmailTemplates.canceled.get("message").format(order_number=order_number)}', 'plain', 'utf-8')
            )

        self.server.send_message(msg)

        self.server.quit()
```

выполнив условно `EmailSender().send_email('to_addr@mail.ru', 'printed', '123456')`

я получаю ошибку, что типа помещено в спам

```
550, b'spam message rejected. Please visit http://help.mail.ru/notspam-support/id?c=### or  report details to abuse@corp.mail.ru. Error code: 4BEEBC0478A891F8C78A09528EE9E06F9E8B3991029FAAD511CED4C34ADE918B. ID: ###'
```

думаю, что `###` особой роли не сыграет, так как на всякий случай закрыл конф.инфу.))

Comment: А вас не посещала мысль о том, что вы забомбили почтовый сервер своими попытками отправки писем? Нет ничего удивительного, что вас поместили в спам-лист.

Comment: Я смог отправить только 1 сообщение. Это не массовая рассылка, а лишь, условно, уведомление. Не думаю, что на сервере лимит 1 отправка

Comment: И что вы хотите, чтобы кто-то из здешней аудиенции связался бы с поддержкой почтового сервиса и попросил бы их не считать спамом ваши письма? Сервер вам отвечает, в чем причина. Более того, я уж очень сомневаюсь, что прямо вот одно-единственное письмо было отправлено, без попыток и дебага. Факт, что сервер расценил активность как спам.

Comment: Есть пароли для внешних приложений. И тогда расценивается отправка прием несколько иным. У меня проект был для организации мониторинг жестких дисков серверов и рассылка почты таким способом. Все работает больше полугода.
https://account.mail.ru/user/2-step-auth/passwords/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

В общем, нужно перейти по ссылке, заполнить форму и написать в описание что-то типа `Хочу использовать ваш SMTP сервер`, ждете где-то день, ну я делал все ночью, а ответили утром, поэтому может все это быстрее делается, и все, можете отправлять сообщения без проблем